# Lookbehind workaround?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, safari

Safari is failing to load my application due to a lookbehind be used (which it does not currently support). Does anyone know a work around for this regex expression?

```
const regExInclude = /^\s*!(include(?:_many|_once|url|sub)?)\s+((?:(?<=\\)[ ]|[^ ])+)(.*)/;
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to match. Provide sample inputs and expected matches.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you only want to match a space when there is a `\` directly to the left.

You might write the pattern matching the `\`  in stead of asserting as well.

Using `(?:\\ |\S)` you either match a non whitespace char, or only a space preceded by `\`

```
^\s*!(include(?:_many|_once|url|sub)?)\s+((?:\\ |\S)+)(.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E8y4R3/1)